# Disable to scrolling tableHeaderView

Tags: uitableview

How could I disable scrolling in `UITableView.tableHeaderView`? I want the table header view to stay on the top of table view controller at all times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The whole point of `tableHeaderView` is that it is embedded in the same `UIScrollView` as the table view cells, hence scrolls.*

Do not use a `UITableViewController`, use a `UIViewController` and position 2 views inside it:

1. A `UIView` to represent the fixed header above
2. A `UITableView` immediately under your header

Make your `UIViewController` subclass adopt both `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols, in much the same way you would in a `UITableViewController`. Connect your `UITableView` to your datasource + delegate in **IB**, pick layout rules for the top view and table view.

A common method would be to add a **Vertical Space Constraint**, such as *Table View.top Equal Header View.bottom*.

Here is how it may look like in **IB**.
Notice the use of a `UIViewController`, not a `UITableViewController`:

[image]